# ByteArrayOutputStream size is zero in PDFWriter?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdf-generation

I have been breaking my head from past 1 hour i am not able to solve this issue...i know its easy to write the PDF in java but my outputstream size is zero,... here is my code..

```
 Document document = new Document();
      try
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream dsf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, dsf);
        document.open();
        document.add(new Paragraph("Some content here"));

        // Set attributes here
        document.addAuthor("Lokesh Gupta");
        document.addCreationDate();
        document.addCreator("HowToDoInJava.com");
        document.addTitle("Set Attribute Example");
        document.addSubject("An example to show how attributes can be added to pdf files.");
        if (frontPageMap != null && !frontPageMap.isEmpty()) {

            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(frontPageMap.size()); // creating
                                                                    // columns.
            table.setWidthPercentage(100); // Width 100%
            table.setSpacingBefore(10f); // Space before table
            table.setSpacingAfter(10f); // Space after table

            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : frontPageMap.entrySet()) {
                PdfPCell tempCell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(entry.getKey()));
                tempCell.setBorderColor(BaseColor.BLUE);
                tempCell.setPaddingLeft(10);
                tempCell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                tempCell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
                table.addCell(tempCell);
            }
            document.add(table);

        }
        System.out.println("Size Of Byte Array is "+dsf.size());
        ByteArrayInputStream bInput = new ByteArrayInputStream(dsf.toByteArray());
        file = new DefaultStreamedContent(bInput, "pdf", fileName);
        document.close();
        writer.close();
```

> NOTE:I am able to print map key values also but When i download PDF the size is zero.

Comment: The final bytes of the PDF are written when you `close()` the document. When I look at your code, I see that you ignore that; you try to do something with the byte array *before* closing the document. That is wrong for obvious reasons.

Comment: The first bytes are written when you `open()` the document. Your allegation that `dsf` doesn't contain any bytes is wrong. It contains at least the header of a PDF file: `PDF-1.` and so on. Of course, if you look at the size of the file, that may look as if it's 0 bytes because it's only a dozen bytes. But it's **not** zero as you claim.

Comment: put the writer line to before System.out.print

Comment: @PSo thanks a lot man

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should finish creating the PDF (with `document.close()` and `writer.close()`), *before* you try to access the contents:

```
    //Finish writing the PDF
    document.close();
    writer.close();
    //now check what's been written:
    System.out.println("Size Of Byte Array is "+dsf.size());
    ByteArrayInputStream bInput = new ByteArrayInputStream(dsf.toByteArray());
    file = new DefaultStreamedContent(bInput, "pdf", fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.close();

writer.close();

ByteArrayInputStream bInput = new ByteArrayInputStream(dsf.toByteArray());

file = new DefaultStreamedContent(bInput, "pdf", fileName);

System.out.println("Size Of Byte Array is "+dsf.size());
```

Add this code. Here you finish writing the pdf file and then  you can print the size of the file. The size my be zero according to the content , but the pdf file generated should have all the records written in it ... Cheers :)